# Padding an empty string to text

Tags: haskell

I am do a crypto exercise that I need to pad an input text to have length of multiple of 16 bytes (AES), and I find that in python I can create a empty (i.e. string of space) with:

> > ' ' * n # whatever integer n is

Is there an equivalent way in haskell? I can do it with simple function using recursion, but just curious is there a way that is even shorter than the python snip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since strings are lists of characters, you can use:

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

For example:

```
replicate 5 'x' == "xxxxx"
```

You can find utility functions like this yourself by searching for a plausible type signature with Hoogle; `replicate` happens to be the first result in a [Hoogle search for `Int -> a -> [a]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D).

If you’re using `Text` instead of `String`, there is an equivalent function in `Data.Text`:

```
replicate :: Int -> Text -> Text

replicate 5 (pack "x") == pack "xxxxx"
```